# Improve Keycloak initialization performance

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, keycloak

I have an Angular single page application that uses Keycloak to decide weather or not users can navigate to a particular route.

This works but adds around significant load time on page refresh making the page feel slow. It seems this is because Keyclock

(1) always does init(...) in on refresh and

(2) init(...) makes a total of 6 calls, causing several round trips.

What if anything can I do to speed up this initial `init(...)`?

---

Some info about the setup.

Keycloak in package.json

```
"keycloak-angular": "^8.1.0",
"keycloak-js": "^12.0.2",
```

Router guards

```
canActivate: [TestingKeyCloak]
```

[These are all the 6 (!) calls made to the Keycloak server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixc1H.png)

Keycloak is running on Google Compute with 2 vCPUs and 4GB of ram.

---

As a point of comparison, I also tried Firebase Authentication which seems to add no noticeable overhead.